# Why didn't Gamora collect the Orb for the Collector?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

In *Guardians of the Galaxy*, Ronan sends Gamora to intercept Peter Quill on his way to the Broker.

[image: Ronan bids Gamora retrieve the Orb]

But, some time earlier, Gamora had accepted the same mission from the Collector. (This occurs in the MCU canon ["Guardians Of The Galaxy Prequel Infinite Comic."](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Prequel_Infinite_Comic))

[image: Taneleer Tivan bids Gamora retrieve the Orb]

When she accepted that mission, she even said, "I do not trust you, Tivan, but I trust Ronan even less. I will obtain the Orb. And you will keep it safe." Why did Gamora apparently disregard her mission from the Collector, wait around for a while, and then only go after the Orb once Ronan sent her to intercept Quill?

What is going on here?

Comment: It's possible that she was planning to, but being at the beck and call of Thanos and Ronan kept her completing the task for Tivan as soon as she had hoped.

Comment: I think Gamora attempts to maintain the appearance of loyalty to Ronan for a decent portion of *Guardians*. As such, when she agreed to get the Orb for the Collector, it was presumably with the understanding that she’d do it when she got the chance to do so without revealing her true loyalties (or lack of them) to Ronan prematurely.

Answer (score 14):

Gamora is (quite rightly) scared of both Ronan the Accuser and her father Thanos, and is basically a slave to them both, a role which does not suit her as well as her adopted sister. As such, disobeying their orders - or maybe even travelling to a planet they have not yet asked to her to visit - would be dangerous for her, and Gamora is smart enough to realise that. So she had to wait for the right moment to attempt to take the Orb, whether that be waiting to be sent to the planet Peter Quill finds it on, or waiting until she has the chance to steal it.

As luck would have it, she is soon sent to get the Orb from Peter Quill for Ronan, thus giving her the perfect opportunity to get the Orb safely, leaving Ronan and her adopted Father clueless to her whereabouts at first, giving her time to go "on the run" and safely deliver it to her contact, The Collector.